# in ajax search how to get set the correct URL?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

JS:

```
function ajaxSearch() {

    var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
    //alert(input_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/search/auto_search",
        data:{search_data:input_data},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //if (data.length > 0) {
               // $('#suggestions').show();
               /// $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
               // $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
            //}
        }
    });
}
```

the URL: `<?php echo base_url(); ?>/search/auto_search` is not working.
Is this code correct for getting url?? please provide solution for this problem?

Comment: `provide solution for this problem` For what problem?

Comment: I dont understand what your goal is. Are you trying to retrieve a URL?

Comment: when i using this code url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/search/auto_search",  and  give alert     did not get  the result

Comment: what do you get when you `echo base_url()` ?

Comment: i did not get the input data

Comment: @codegodie   get  nothing

Comment: What is the generated JS code once PHP is done?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting anything when you use `echo base_url()` is because you have not defined this variable in `config.php`. Go to `application/config/config.php` and check the following line:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourURLhere'; //enter your url
```

Also make sure you are loading the right helper:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: but  i mentioned the url in config.php   then what is the problem??

Comment: would you like me to help you remotely through Teamviewer?

Comment: But when i  echo out url outside the ajax    i got the url but  when i echo  out the url inside   i did not get it? what is the reson for that?

Comment: where is this Javascript located? is it embedded on the same page in your PHP view? or is it its own JS file?

Comment: @codiegodie  javascript is in js folder

Comment: Thats the problem. you are using php tags inside a JS file: thats incorrect. what you need to do is add something like this in the head of your html: `<script>var base_url = "<?= base_url() ?>";</script>`. Once you have that in the very top of your HTML.. then you can link other JS files referencing that `base_url` variable.